# class java.lang.String can not be converted to an Long while DynamoDB creating table

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to create dynamodb table using php-aws-sdk

```
set_time_limit(0);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once 'aws/aws-autoloader.php';

use Aws\DynamoDb\DynamoDbClient;

$ddb = DynamoDbClient::factory(array(
    'key'    => $_SERVER['AWS_KEY']),
    'secret' => $_SERVER['AWS_SECRET']),
    'region' => $_SERVER['AWS_REGION'])
));

$name = 'test';

$ddb->createTable(array(
    'TableName' => $name,
    'AttributeDefinitions' => array(
        array(
            'AttributeName' => 'Event ID',
            'AttributeType' => 'S'
        )
    ),
    'KeySchema' => array(
        array(
            'AttributeName' => 'Event ID',
            'KeyType' => 'HASH'
        )
    ),
    'ProvisionedThroughput' => array(
        'ReadCapacityUnits' => $_SERVER['DDB_READ_CAPACITY_UNITS']),
        'WriteCapacityUnits' => $_SERVER['DDB_WRITE_CAPACITY_UNITS']),
    )
));

echo $name;
```

It is working successfully on local machine, but I have error by running script on Elasticbeanstalk

> Fatal error: Uncaught Aws\DynamoDb\Exception\DynamoDbException: AWS
>   Error Code: SerializationException, Status Code: 400, AWS Request ID:
>   HTTCDOVSES4RU0V8IVIQFGREL7VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG, AWS Error Type:
>   client, AWS Error Message: class java.lang.String can not be converted
>   to an Long, User-Agent: aws-sdk-php2/2.6.12 Guzzle/3.9.1 curl/7.36.0
>   PHP/5.5.12 thrown in
>   /var/app/current/aws/Aws/Common/Exception/NamespaceExceptionFactory.php
>   on line 91

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect, since the error is talking about a bad string to long (number) conversion, that your `DDB_READ_CAPACITY_UNITS` and `DDB_WRITE_CAPACITY_UNITS` values are problem being read as strings from `$_SERVER`. Try casting/converting them to integers.

```
'ProvisionedThroughput' => array(
    'ReadCapacityUnits' => (int) $_SERVER['DDB_READ_CAPACITY_UNITS'],
    'WriteCapacityUnits' => (int) $_SERVER['DDB_WRITE_CAPACITY_UNITS'],
)
```